# What is the difference between .pb SavedModel and .tf SavedModel?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

**For.pb SavedModel :** `model.save("my_model")` *default saves to .pb*

**For .tf SavedModel :** `model.save("my_model",save_format='.tf')`

I would like to know the difference between these two formats. Are they both SavedModel? Are they both the same ? Which is better? Both are TensorFlow extension?

Answer (score 3):

See the documentation of [`tf.keras.Model.save`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#save). `save_format` can have one of two values:

- `tf` (default in TensorFlow 2.x) means TensorFlow format, a [SavedModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) protocol buffers file.
- `h5` (default in TensorFlow 1.x) means the HDF5 Keras format, defined back when Keras was completely independent of TensorFlow and aimed to support multiple backends without being tied to anyone in particular.

In TensorFlow 2.x you should not ever need `h5`, unless you want to produce a file compatible with older versions or something like that. SavedModel is also more integrated into the TensorFlow ecosystem, for example if you want to use it with TensorFlow Serving.

Comment: Then what is .pb format? I use tf2.0 and using .save to get a SavedModel gives me a .pb file in it. 
My question is difference btw .pb and .tf.

Comment: @Krishnadas The `.pb` file extension, used in general for any serialised protocol buffers, and in this case for the TensorFlow `SavedModel` format. There is no `.tf` file extension (that is, you can use whatever extension you want for your files, but that is not a conventionally used one). When you use `save_format='tf'` you get a `.pb` file with the model in TensorFlow format. If you use `save_format='h5'` you get a `.h5` file with the model in Keras format.

Comment: Are there any differences in the data they contain, or the operations/ features they support?

Comment: @BenButterworth Yes, `SavedModel` is more general. E.g. from the documentation of [`tf.keras.Model.save`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#save): "Models built with the Sequential and Functional API can be saved to both the HDF5 and SavedModel formats. Subclassed models can only be saved with the SavedModel format".